# Resources for learning the shorshei mitzvos of the Rambam

Tags: product-recommendation, rambam, mishneh-torah

The Rambam lays down 14 principles, which he terms shorshei mitzvos, to determine which mitzvos are part of the 613. Besides the commentaries in the standard Mishne Torah, are there any other books written on the shorshei mitzvos? Are there shiurim on the shorshei mitzvos available online?

Comment: You can find in Sefaria the main commentary, i.e. the Hasagot Haramban. And others. It is very important to learn the Shorashim. In Atar Daat you have a translation from Rabbi Kappach, It is also avaiable in Hebrewbooks. For every Shoresh learn the Hasagot Haramban, it is not less interesting than the Shorashim. Sefaria furnishes all what you need.

Comment: Can you post a link? I couldn't find it.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sefer_HaMitzvot?lang=he

Comment: @kouty he asked for commentaries besides the standard ones on the page.

Comment: I know commentaries beside but not online sorry.

Comment: https://www.ravchaimilson.com/shiurim

Answer (score 4):

[R. Chaim Ilson](https://www.ravchaimilson.com/) has a lengthy series of shiurim on this, with several hours per shoresh. These shiurim are available on YUTorah.

[image: Screenshot of list of shiurim]

From the linked website:

> Rav Ilson studied the *Shoroshim* with Rabbi Joseph B. Soloveitchik zt”l and has been delivering *shiurim* on the *Shoroshim* for more than two decades.  These *shiurim* are the basis of the project, a *Sefer* explicating the *Sefer Hamitzvoth*.